# Program Error for userInput

Tags: c, user-input

What does this mean?

```
void userInput(char row, int column, int quad, char rotation) {

scanf("%c%d%d%c",&row,&column,&quad,&rotation);

switch(row){
case 'A' :    if(column<=3)
                  q1[0][column] = 'x';
              else if(column<=6)
                  q2[0][column-4] = 'x';  
              break;
```

I get an error for invalid type 'int[int]' for array subscript for:
 q1[0][column] = 'x';

Someone help me fix this?

Comment: `q1[0]` but `q1` is an integer...

Comment: You've declared `q1` and `q2` as plain `int`s in your parameter list, not as arrays.  What are the types of the expressions you're passing to `userInput`?

Comment: if I take it out of the parameter, then I get the error that q1 isn't declared

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]_

Answer (score 0):

`q1` and `q2` are `int`s, you can't use array subscripts with them.  They should be arrays in your parameter list: `int q1[][COL_CNT]`, where `COL_CNT` is the number of columns.

**EDIT:** I see you've removed `q1` and `q2` from your parameters, which will also not work, as they now don't exist at all.  You need to pass them as arrays of arrays of ints in the way I showed above.

Comment: Where do I pass them?  I'm a beginner in programming and I do not understand some of these materials. What parameter list?

Comment: In place of where you had them before.  The parameter list is the `(char row, int column, int quad, char rotation)` part.  Add `int q1[][COL_CNT], int q2[]COL_CNT]` to the end of that, where `COL_CNT` is the number of columns in the array.

Comment: But even then from using my logic, COL_CNT wouldn't be declared and would give me a compiling error

Comment: @Navmi You don't know how big your arrays are?  COL_CNT isn't declared in your code, which is why I told you that it's equal to the number of columns in your array.  Ideally, you'd define COL_CNT: `#define COL_CNT 10`, but you could also just type `int q1[][10]` directly, though "magic numbers" like that are frowned upon.